# How to move document from one html to another (MongoDB/Node.js)

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I just studying mongodb and node.js, and i met a problem. I need to write a request so that when I click on the "Rent" button the document moves to rent and disappears from the available ones. How do I implement this?

Sorry if it stupid question.

[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmxgd.png)

Schema:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')

const schema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: false
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    default: false
  }
})

module.exports = model('Rent', schema)
```

html of available :

```
 <div class="rent__title">

        <img src="https://emojio.ru/images/apple-b/1f6b2.png" alt="">
        <h2 id="rh">Available bicycles </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="rent__list">
        {{#if rents.length}}
            <ul class="ul">
                {{#each rents}}
                    <li class="rent">
                        <form action="/rented" method="POST">
                            <label>
                                {{#if completed}}


                                    <span class="aval">{{title}} &nbsp / &nbsp {{type}} &nbsp/ &nbsp {{price}}</span>
                                {{/if}}

                                <input type="hidden" value="{{_id}}" name="id">
                                <span class="rent__buttons">
                                <button formaction="/rented" class="btn b1" >Rent</button>

                                <button formaction="/delete" class="btn b2" >Delete</button>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        {{else}}
            <p>No rent!</p>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
```

routes:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const Todo = require('../models/Todo')
const Rented = require('../models/Todo')
const router = Router()



router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const todos = await Todo.find({})

  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Todos list',
    isIndex: true,
    todos
  })
})

router.get('/create', (req, res) => {
  res.render('create', {
    title: 'Create new rent',
    type: 'Choose type',
    price: '$',
    status: 'false',
    isCreate: true
  })
})

router.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
  const todo = new Todo({
    title: req.body.title,
    type: req.body.type,
    price: req.body.price
  })

  await todo.save()
  res.redirect('/')
})

router.post('/rented', async (req, res) => {
  const rent = await Todo.findById(req.body.id)

  rent.rented = !!req.body.rented
  await rent.save()


  res.redirect('/')
})

router.post('/delete', async (req, res) => {
  const todo = await Todo.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.id)
  await todo.save()


  res.redirect('/')

});
```

module.exports = router

Comment: What you can do is add a condition while traversing over the record, when someone presses a rent key, update the record in DB and subsequently either remove the row from dom in case of success (recommended) or refresh the whole page.

Comment: @mehta-rohan can you show me example of a request which will do it ?

Comment: what does that /rented formaction do?

Comment: @mehta-rohan Nothing for now. I just want to call this request as "/rented". This is the question I'm talking about

Comment: in this route, you have to use mongo update query, you can search it over

Comment: @mehta-rohan but how it will shows on html page, i can't understand

Comment: @mehta-rohan i guess i need to make one more collection and move document there by button click. But how it make ?

Comment: Not at all, you have to fetch only the required data on other page and fetch the data accordingly, a different route will work, but separate document makes no sense

Comment: share your API code where you manage all these routes

Comment: @mehta-rohan i shared> check it

Comment: instead of creating a new collection, update Todo collection with a flag `rented: true` and on your rented page, make a new path /getRented and in mongo query use `rented: true` and display the result.

Comment: @mehta-rohan can u write this part of code, cz i don't understand at all )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new route as

```
router.get('/getRented', async (req, res) => {
    const todos = await Todo.find({rented:true})

    res.render('rented', {
    title: 'Rented Todos list',
    isIndex: true,
    todos
    })
})

router.post('/rented', async (req, res) => {
  //req.body.id
  //update this code by rented:true
})
```

Comment: One last question, how to make this 'rented' page show in 'index' page, cz i don't need another page with rent bikes

Comment: part of your code is missing, not able to see how todos reached the index page.

Comment: how about github?

Comment: looks like i dont have enough permission to push the code

Comment: Give me ur git hub, I let u permission

Comment: Thank u so match <3

Comment: read it. it's not the best structure, a lot of learning needs to be done...good luck